# How to add multiple ips in sssd.conf file and how to check failover is happening is working

Tags: ubuntu, sssd

Can some one help me to add multiple servers in sssd.conf file , if the primary ad server is down it should pick the secondary servers and how do we check failover is working fine or not. Any parameters to add in the sssd.conf file.

Comment: Did you try `man -k sssd`?

Comment: No haven't tried that will try to check and update in this forum... Thanks @U.Windl

Comment: Tried it worked all the details were give and failover as well..

Comment: ad_server,ad_backup_server,ldap_opt_timeout,dns_resolver_timeout,dns_resolver_op_timeout should be utilised

Comment: Maybe then answer your question (*not* in comments), providing the details. Alternatively if you think the question is not worth it, you can also delete it.